# Poset and graph on one plot

Tags: plot, graphics, graph-theory, sage

I'm dealing with structures where there is a poset and an extra undirected graph on the same vertices which is a subgraph of the poset's incomparability graph. In my physical notebook I draw the hasse diagram of the poset and add the extra graph's edges in a different color. Can I do something like that in sage?

Comment: Not a sage user, but perhaps you could represent both structures in a single `multigraph` as described [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph.html); you can then keep track of different edge colors using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639169/networkx-change-color-width-according-to-edge-attributes-inconsistent-result).

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem yeah I can do differently colored edges but if I do it as a general (multi)graph then it won't show the hasse diagram nicely leveled

Comment: I suppose you could specify node coordinates manually (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689391/how-to-reshape-a-networkx-graph-in-python)), but it does sound like a bit of work. Maybe someone with sage experience will know a better way.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem this way I can't use the poset drawing from sage right?